# counting no of array element an array

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, protractor

ineed to get the number of elements created at every instance when a button is click

```
<a class="item-content ng-binding" ng-href="#/lead/details/0/quotation/view/0/" target="_self" href="#/lead/details/0/quotation/view/0/">
            2015-10-22 - 1000674
        </a>
```

every time i click on a button a new element is been created with a serial number i need to find out the count of elements after every button clicks 
i used

```
var quotationNumber         = element.all(by.css('.item-content.ng-binding'));

it('should display Correct Quotation number in Lead Page',function(){
        expect(quotationNumber.getText()).count();
    });
```

my terminal sends an error message   TypeError: expect(...).count is not a function. i need the size of that array elements. could some one help me to fix this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `element.all` the returned promise has method `count` the `getText` called on `element.all(selector).getText()` returns an array of text so for that you can use `length`

```
var quotationNumber = element.all(by.css('.item-content.ng-binding'));

it('should display Correct Quotation number in Lead Page',function(){
        expect(quotationNumber.count()).toBe(3);
    });
```

Comment: thank you for your answer  consider that i dont know th value "toBe(3)" in this case what should i do

Comment: live i will update it but i want to use that array size in my next test case

Comment: @YokeshVaradhan In that case, you can use various methods that jasmine provides like - `.toBeGreaterThan()` or `.not.toBeNull()` or store the value everytime a new element adds and then use that value in the expect statement.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing `expect(quotationNumber.getText()).count();` to `expect(quotationNumber.getText().count());` ?

Comment: I'm very sceptic it is the right way to test this, what if you should have 10 quotation but because of faulty code you got one? it's still going to pass this lousy test

Comment: I'm guessing the test is to check if the number exists. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: number exists and to view the array size